# CLLocationManager multiple delegate calls Apple Watch

Tags: swift, watchkit, cllocationmanager, watchos-2

I am trying to use `CLLocationManager` on a WatchKit app, and I think I am experiencing unexpected behavior:

I have a CLLocationManager as a class variable named `manager`, and when I call `self.manager.requestLocation();` on the Apple Watch, sometimes, it calls the delegate `didUpdateLocations` only once, and other times the delegate gets called multiple times.

Is this expected behavior, even though I only called the `requestLocation` method once? If not, is there a workaround?

Comment: if requestLocation work like startUpdateLocation it's normally that the method didUpdateLocations gets called multiple times..

Comment: @Nekfeu I think that it is only supposed to update it one time, because the method is also available on iOS. It also does not provide continuous updates, all updates appear to occur for less than 5 seconds.

Comment: ok so you think the problem only exist on AppleWatch?

Comment: @Nekfeu I believe so, based on my testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It normal, due to the fact that it sometimes adjusts the location quickly if its not 100% correct. At least thats what I've concluded. That being said, you really should offload location fetching to the phone instead of using the watch if possible due to battery concerns.